# How can I check if my pod identity is working for node.js application?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I have used [this script](https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2020/01/21/access-keyvault-from-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-with-an-asp-net-core-application-using-a-managed-identity/) to implement manage identity for NODE.js application by using below script. How can I check if it is working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do few activities to confirm that it's using Pod Identity is working properly.

1. Print the token which you get from MSI token endpoint `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token`
2. Make a GET call to instance metadata endpoint `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01`

For more details refer [doc](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity#6-deployment-and-validation) and [code](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/blob/master/cmd/demo/main.go) which is written in GoLang but easy to translate to nodejs or any other language.